# When did Magdalen return to England?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, british-english, silent-letters

From *Mary of Magdala*, the female disciple of Jesus Christ cited in the New Testament,  we have the names *Magdalen* and *Magdalene*.  Oxford Dictionaries includes the archaic definitions of  magdalen, *[a reformed prostitute](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/magdalen)*, and  *a home for reformed prostitutes.*

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Magdalene), the Greek female name *Magdalene* was anglicized to *Maudelen* in the early 14th century. In Aramaic, *Maghdela* meant “elevated, great, magnificent” while in Hebrew מגדל, *migdal* (or *migdol*), meant “tower” or “fortress”. From the comments, @John Lawler mentions that in modern Hebrew - *migdalor* stands for ‘lighthouse’ lit = tower + light.

Two eminent and prestigious English Colleges are named after the catholic saint but their names, although spelled Magdalene and Magdalen, in keeping with tradition are pronounced /ˈmɔːdlᵻn/ **mawd**-*lin*

### Magdalene College Cambridge

Founded 1428

> One of the questions we are asked most commonly is about the pronunciation of the name of the College! Though nowadays spelt in the biblical and continental way, 'Magdalene', the College name is customarily pronounced **'Maudlyn'**.
>
> The College at its refoundation by Lord Audley in 1542, was dedicated to St Mary Magdalene. The choice of the name of Mary Magdalene appears to have had a touch of vanity. In many early documents, the name is clearly spelt as pronounced: 'Maudleyn', containing within it the name of Audley himself! The final 'e' on Magdalene was an attempt, with the advent of the postal service in the mid nineteenth-century, to distinguish us from our sister College, Magdalen Oxford.
>
> <sup>[Magdalen College; University of Cambridge](http://www.magd.cam.ac.uk/why-maudlyn/)</sup>

### Magdalen College Oxford

Founded 1480

> People are regularly surprised at why Magdalen College is pronounced **“Maudlin”**. This charter offers a reason why. Waynflete decreed that his College should be known as “Collegium beatae Mariae Magdalenae” in Latin and “Maudelayne College” in English. In the 15th century, English speakers called St. Mary Magdalene “St. Mary Maudelayne” (or “Mawdelayne”), without the “g” – like “Madeleine” in French. It was only later that we put the “g” back. Magdalen College, however, like Magdalene College, Cambridge, has preserved the old pronunciation of her name.
>
> <sup>[Magdalen College; University of Oxford](http://www.magd.ox.ac.uk/libraries-and-archives/treasure-of-the-month/news/foundation-charter/)</sup>

It's pretty straight forward how the English adjective *[**maudlin**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maudlin)*, meaning ‘tearful’ and ‘highly sentimental’, was derived from the Anglicized name ***Maudlene*** but less straightforward is the whereabouts of the letter "g" that must have been seen and — more importantly — heard in *migdol*, *Magdala* and in the Greek *Magdalene*. In fact, the "g" is included in the  following IPA transcriptions: `/ˈmaɡdəlɪn/`, `/ˈmæɡdələn/` and `/ˈmæg də lən/`. Unbeknown to me, the last ‘e’ in [Magdalene](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/magdalene) is sometimes  pronounced /ɪ/ as in `mæɡdəˈliːnɪ`.

So although the "g" was absent from *Maudlene*, both Cambridge and Oxford later sought to reinsert the "g" in their college names. Why?

- Why did Cambridge and Oxford replace *Maudelyn* and *Maudlin* with Magdalen(e), and when exactly did this happen?
- Why  didn't the spelling also change for *maudlin*, when the name Magdalen(e) and the noun *magdalen* was introduced in England?

Comment: The Oxford college of the same name is also pronounced *maudlin*. In Norwich there is a very old street - Magdalen Street - which the locals pronounce *maglun street*. I am not sure how the Cambridge townsfolk, as opposed to the students and dons, pronounce "Magdalen Street, Cambridge". But it would be interesting to know if there are any Cambridge folk out there.

Comment: @WS2 interesting pronunciation *maglun*, so the letters "d" , "a"   are completely silent.

Comment: ***Magdalene:*** From a title which meant "of Magdala". Mary Magdalene, a character in the New Testament, was named thus because she was from Magdala - a village on the Sea of Galilee whose name meant "tower" in Hebrew. She was cleaned of evil spirits by Jesus and then remained with him during his ministry, witnessing the crucifixion and the resurrection. She was a popular saint in the Middle Ages, and the name became common then. ***In England it is traditionally rendered Madeline, while Magdalene or Magdalen is the learned form.***

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well *maglun* is the way it is pronounced in the local accent. The more gentrified of the locals may say *magdalen* street.

Comment: @Josh I think we are all well aware of the name's origin, Josh. But your final sentence, in bold, is not the case at all. The learned form used in  Oxford and Cambridge, both of which have colleges of that name is *Maudlin*. A teacher at my school (60 years ago), a Latin scholar as well as being an ordained priest, used to insist, when reading from the New Testament to pronounce the name *Mary Magdaleney*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But no one says *Maudlin street*.

Comment: Our modern English translations of the Bible have gone back to the Latin text for the form Magdalene. ***But in early French, the g dropped out and the word became Madelaine. When the name was taken into Middle English from the early French texts, its form was Maudeleyn and later Maudlin.*** In the Middle Ages, religious artists painting scenes of the crucifixion and burial of Jesus showed Mary as weeping. In time her name became an adjective for a tearful show of emotion and later especially for an exaggerated display of emotion. http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?maudlin

Comment: The /gd/ cluster is there in the original (and still is in modern Hebrew - _migdalor_ 'lighthouse' lit = tower + light), and it's not hard at all to see how the first voiced stop of a cluster of two gets dropped. As to reintroduction, that's an ongoing process in a consciously archaizing environment like Oxbridge. Probably it's been reintroduced in many different places, times, and contexts over the centuries.

Comment: It is a common misconception at the University of Oxford that this college's name is pronounced in modern style, while Magdalen College Oxford is pronounced "Maudlyn." Both Colleges are, in fact, pronounced exactly the same, although the root of this misconception may arise from the two streets in Oxford, one of which uses the same pronunciation as the colleges (Magdalen Bridge), and the other of which uses the modern pronunciation, as it is adjacent to the Anglican Church of St. Mary Magdalene, across from Balliol College. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdalene_College,_Cambridge

Comment: @Josh have you read the excerpts taken from the University of Cambridge and Oxford? The pronunciation of the colleges called Magdalen(e) is written and placed in bold in both excerpts. It's the reason *why* I searched into this the first place. I'm not asking "how" to pronounce the colleges' names in Cambridge or in Oxford, but why the missing "g" was reinserted, and (consequently) "why" has the traditional pronunciation stuck for five hundred years.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't  understand why you call it the missing g. Though the names have the same origin, they have distinct histories from the Middle Ages.

Comment: OK, maybe missing "g" is the wrong expression, but today the names Maudelyne and Maudelin no longer exist. No one is called that, whereas Magdelen (Madge) and Magdalyn, although no longer in fashion,  do exist.

Comment: I think what has today survived of the non-g older names is Madeline. No surprise Oxford and Cambridge introduced the original, biblical spelling, after all they are cultural centres.

Comment: @Josh why is it no surprise that the colleges were later spelled Magdalene but still retained their former pronunciation? On the contrary, I think that is quite remarkable and nothing of the sort happens in the Italian language. Name me one word in the Italian language whose pronunciation is archaic/obsolete compared to its orthography. The history of Italian is just as long, if not more so than English.

Comment: It would have made more sense to have retained the **original spelling** if the universities  wanted to retain its **former pronunciation**.

Comment: Well, there are places, streets, squares etc, which have been named after contemporary important persons, but still people call them by the previous older name for instance. They generally don't even realize that they have been renamed. Anyway the fact that the two most important Universities  decided  to adopt the original name whose spelling was curruptef by French is no surprise. Who at that time could  pronunce it correctly?  Probably just the few learned ones. The older pronounciation somehow prevailed.

Comment: Anyway, the point is that name Magdalene was changed by the French in Middle Ages. The English just adopted it and later opted for the original version.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know the history of Italian orthography, but of all the Romance languages it has been the most conservative and so spoken likely not to differ much from orthography. English on the other hand is well known for its chaotic spelling sometimes solidified on whim.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Silent letters have been introduced many times based on (sometimes faulty) history: [debt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=debt), [island](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=island)!=[isle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=isle). My guess is that the reintroduction of 'g' in 'Magdalen' (pronounced 'maudlin') occurred in Late ME, well after Chaucer but before Shakespeare.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As to why, I'm sure there are ME documents that show one guy starting to do it, similar to debt and isle, and then everybody following that afterwards. But those documents are lost now. That guy may well have had a treatise on why it was important to add back in letters that were no longer pronounced for some classicist/humanist reasons, or just because. You'd have to ask them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As an aside, when did the 'g' in 'gli' in Italian get introduced. I'm pretty sure nothing like it was there in Latin, so it wasn't reintroduced, but it certainly is a specially introduced non-pronouncing letter..

Comment: @Mitch In Italian the name is spelled with double "d" Maddalena. I'm no expert on the Italian language but I think the double d (which is audible) immitates the "dg" sound.

Comment: @Mitch Sorry, I was sure you asked about the name Magdalen in Italian. As for the *g* in "gli" I have no idea about its history. But the *g* in gli is NOT prounced as "glee"  or as "lee"

Comment: Is it too far off the wall to suggest that if the traditional pronunciation of anything important to scripture in English stuck for five hundred years, that might very well be because roughly, 500 years is when we started get English translations of The Bible?

In any case, how many languages at very least are involved in any translation from anything appearing in an original Gospel to modern English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "g" never completely left England in the first place. It was one of several spellings.

For example, the first full English translation of the New Testament, from the Latin Vulgate rather than the original Greek,  was the [unofficial translation](http://www.bibledbdata.org/onlinebibles/wycliffe_nt/40_027.htm) by Wycliffe in 1382.  In the space of 11 verses (Matthew  27  verse 56 to 28 verse1) Wycliffe  spelt the name  three different ways: "Magdalene", "Maudelene" and "Mawdelene".

Chaucer  also used spellings with and without the g.  King Henry VII (reigned 1485 - 1509)  wrote to the Oxford college spelling its name with a"g",  and Henry VIII used various spellings. [Reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9ZWDBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=%22magdalen%20college%22%20spelling&source=bl&ots=WDyN-rXuua&sig=RIKJNHu92N3NVDxIJ85MD2O9vT8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRnJODxf7SAhVpL8AKHTuaApE4ChDoAQhKMAw#v=onepage&q=%22magdalen%20college%22%20spelling&f=false)

Mary Magdalene was said to have lived in France for many years, and there are many stories and legends about her time there.  Some even suggested she may have been "Mrs Jesus". Her cult was especially popular in France, and with the Normans who conquered England. Also the Knights Templar held her in great regard.   The first "a"  in Magdalene was pronounced in England similar to in France,  to rhyme with  ball and water. Said this way the "g" sound virtually disappears, and this is the reason for it often  being omitted.

The Gospels tell us that Mary Magdalene  accompanied Jesus on a preaching tour (Luke 8), and may have provided financial support. She was present at the Crucifixion and was the first person known to have met Jesus after the Resurrection (e.g. Matthew 27 and 28, Mark 15 and 16; John 19 and 20). It was she who told the male disciples Christ had risen, though they did not believe her until they saw for themselves.

The  Gospels also refer to a Mary at Bethany (John 11), sister to Martha and Lazarus; and to a  penitent "sinful woman" whose tears wet Jesus' feet, which she then dried with her hair (Luke 7). The early Church had long speculated that these two women and Mary Magdalene were all one and the same person, and Pope Gregory in the sixth century asserted  this was so. This is known as the Composite Magdalene.  The portrayal  of Mary Magdalene as weeping and sentimental (washing Jesus' feet with tears as well as moping about in the garden after His death) led to her association with weeping sentimentality and to our word "maudlin".

The sixteenth century saw several mass-produced Bibles in English, beginning with Tyndale's illegal translation in 1526.  The first official English Bible, the Great Bible of Henry VIII,  was produced in 1539, and copies placed in every parish church. The Geneva Bible was produced abroad during Queen Mary's reign  (1553 to 1558) , and very widely circulated when Elizabeth succeeded her. Another official version, the Bishops' Bible was produced in 1568, followed by the King James Version of 1611. All these  Bibles agreed in spelling  Magdalene with a "g".  Indeed the original Greek word, which  begins mu-alpha-gamma-delta, pretty much mandated this.

As spelling became standardised the standard spelling of Biblical names naturally conformed to the spelling used in  Bibles.  This applied to Oxford and Cambridge colleges as to everyone else. We will not find a decision by the colleges to officially change the way they spelt their names, with effect from a certain date, because spelling wasn't consistent or official to begin with.

It is possible that the  older pronunciation would have lasted longer if her cult had persisted. The Reformation reduced the role of saints generally. They were no longer prayed to. Although the feast days of the male disciples were retained,  Mary Magdalene's was cancelled, lingering only as a note in the Church of England calendar, but with no special prayers or readings. The identification of Mary Magdalene with Martha's sister and the tearful penitent was dismissed as papal speculation. The French legends were of no further interest.  To Protestant England, "Mary Magdalene" was simply not the woman she used to be. At most, she was one facet of her former persona. As the first witness of the Resurrection she was still a saint, but people largely lost interest in her. Calvin even went so far as to call her  foolish and unspiritual, and saw Christ's appearance to her first as a reproof to the men,  who deserved to be taught by oxen and asses, never mind women! Had she retained her place in popular devotion she might well have retained her pronunciation, due to constant use. As it was, her name was pronounced, when read,  as written.

This [paper](http://www.jfrankhenderson.com/pdf/Disappearance_Feast_MaryMagdalene.pdf) by Frank Henderson explores the dropping of her feast day in England, and considers he attitudes of the Reformers generally.

Very commonly where a name becomes a word, as maudlin did, the word takes on a separate existence independent of the person. In this particular case Mary Magdalene was no longer definitively identified with the weeping penitent woman anyway, so there was even less reason why the word maudlin should follow the Biblical pronunciation, or spelling, of Magdalene.

As regards the colleges the pronunciation stuck the way many place names stick, because people see no need to change them, especially from two syllables to three or four.

Answer (score 3):

In Middle English, the g is sometimes interpreted as a yogh (throu**gh**, wi**gh**t, bri**gh**t), and therefore gets elided.  Compare the Old English word þegn rendered in Modern English as thane.

The re-introduction of the g probably comes from the desire to differentiate the common word from the more academic usage, and that meant harkening back to Latin.

Comment: Any idea when the letter "g" was reintroduced?

Comment: Mmm ... but the /g/ had already been dropped in Old French (*Madelaine, Madeleine*) before the name entered English, so I think we have to look to sound changes in French rather than OE>ME.

Comment: @StoneyB Chambers's Etymological Dictionary (1867) says [Maudlin, contra. from Old E. Maudeleyne] https://books.google.com/books?id=hSRTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR8&dq=chambers+etymological+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS9qaOjv3SAhUB8CYKHXkYDm8Q6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=maudalin&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD In 1867 English philology was in its infancy, and what we call "Old English" was "Anglo-Saxon" or "A.S."  "Old E." would have meant what we call "Middle English"--which is when the name entered our tongue from O.F.

Answer (score 3):

Printed in 1573 is [The whole workes of W. Tyndall, Iohn Frith, and Doct. Barnes, three worthy Martyrs, and principall teachers of this Churche of England, collected and compiled in one Tome togither, beyng before scattered, & now in Print here exhibited to the Church](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A68831.0001.001/1:4.2?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=Magdalene%20College), which says:

> First touching the birth and parentage of this blessed Martyre in Christ, hée was borne in the edge of Wales, and brought vp from a childe in the vniuersitie of Oxforde, where hée by long continuance grew, and encreased aswell in the knowledge of tongues, and other liberall artes, as especially in the knowlege of Scriptures, whereunto his mind was singularly addicted: Insomuch that hée liyng in Magdalene hall, read priuelye to certaine studentes, and felowes of **Magdalene College**, some percell of Diuinitie, instructing them in the knowlege, and trueth of the Scriptures.

Furthermore, in the Early English Text database there are about 100 documents from the 1470-1570 time period that use the spelling "Magdalene" plus 39 for "Magdalen".

For example, there is one [from 1480](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A23587.0001.001/1:3.218?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1570;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=Magdalene) that refers to "mary Magdalene day"

The oldest references to "Maudlin College" are in the 1700s, for example the article [The Account of Colleges and Halls of the University of Cambridge](https://books.google.com/books?id=CvoqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA163&dq=%22Maudlin%20college%20was%20originally%20founded%20by%20edward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir4MHonvzSAhWG5iYKHeCFAAEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Maudlin%20college%20was%20originally%20founded%20by%20edward%22&f=false) *The London Magazine, Or, Gentleman's Monthly Intelligencer* April 1748 which says:

> *Magdalen*, or *Maudlin-College*, was originally founded by *Edward Stafford*, Duke of *Buckingham*, in 1519, 11 Henry VII, on the Site of *St. Gile's* Priory by the Name of *Buckingham College*: But he being beheaded *Thomas* Lord *Audley*, Lord Chancellor of *England*, obtain'd of K. *Henry* VII in 1542, a Grant of this College, and a Charter incorporating the Society by the Name of *The Master and Fellows of* St. Mary Magdalen College, *in the fair University of* Cambridge.

Concerning Oxford the 1726 [Terræ-filius: Or, The Secret History of the University of Oxford](https://books.google.com/books?id=O-84AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22Maudlin%20college%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYgbf1o_zSAhVC5CYKHYAQCvMQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Maudlin%20college%22&f=false) refers to "Maudlin College" in a 1 June entry.

Comment: Is your answer that "Magdalene" was in current usage at the time that the two colleges were founded?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 basically, yes.  The one in Cambridge was originally "Buckingham College", but "Magdalene" was in use when it was renamed by Audley. And "Magdalene" was in use in 1480 when the Oxford college was founded.